# Aggregation in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregation

I need some help with aggregation problem in oracle SQL. I hope it's not too much simple, but i really don't know how to do that.

I have the following columns:

```
Customer_ID  (int)
Countract_ID (int)
```

- Each contract can including a several different customers
- Each customer can be included in a several contracts.

I need to add a new column with the average number of the contracts that each member has in addition (including the current one). For example:

```
ContractID  |CustomerID | "AVG sum of contracs per member in the contract"
123         | 11        |(3 + 2 + 1) / 3 = 2
123         | 22        |(3 + 2 + 1) / 3 = 2
123         | 33        |(3 + 2 + 1) / 3 = 2
321         | 11        |(3 + 2 + 2 + 1)  / 4  = 2
321         | 55        |(3 + 2 + 2 + 1)  / 4  = 2
321         | 22        |(3 + 2 + 2 + 1)  / 4  = 2
321         | 88        |(3 + 2 + 2 + 1)  / 4  = 2
987         | 11        |(3 + 2  + 1 + 1) / 4 = 1.75
987         | 55        |(3 + 2  + 1 + 1) / 4 = 1.75
987         | 99        |(3 + 2  + 1 + 1) / 4 = 1.75
987         | 77        |(3 + 2  + 1 + 1) / 4 = 1.75
```

Is anybody know what is the query for such as aggregation?

Comment: no more time - maybe tomorrow...

Comment: You data structure isn't entirely clear for me. Perhaps you could use [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to set up a small Schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, where we use a couple of analytic functions: `count() over()` and `avg() over()`.

```
-- sample of data
with t1(Contractid ,Customerid) as(
  select 123 , 11 from dual union all
  select 123 , 22 from dual union all
  select 123 , 33  from dual union all
  select 321 , 11  from dual union all
  select 321 , 55  from dual union all
  select 321 , 22  from dual union all
  select 321 , 88  from dual union all
  select 987 , 11  from dual union all
  select 987 , 55  from dual union all
  select 987 , 99  from dual union all
  select 987 , 77  from dual
 )
 -- the query
 -- analytic functions cannot be nested, thus inline vew
 select contractid
      , customerid
      , avg(cnt) over(partition by contractid) as average
  from ( select contractid
              , customerid    
              , count(contractid) over(partition by customerid) cnt
           from t1 )
 order by contractid, customerid
```

Result:

```
CONTRACTID CUSTOMERID    AVERAGE
---------- ---------- ----------
       123         11          2
       123         22          2
       123         33          2
       321         11          2
       321         22          2
       321         55          2
       321         88          2
       987         11       1.75
       987         55       1.75
       987         77       1.75
       987         99       1.75

11 rows selected
```

[Sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b1c90/2)

Comment: Thank you alot! I'm curious, is this query can be implemented only with analytic functions, or it can be implemented also in the simple way?

Comment: @user3928712 When you say "simple way", what do you mean exactly? No, I'm sure there more than a few ways to get it done, with different degree of efficiency.

Comment: I wanted to ask if this this calculation can be implemented in query without analytic function. that's it.